# Webpage won't render my Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am saving a text file as index.html and using that to test this function, however nothing happens when I click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="testamber()">Click here</button>

        <script>
            var testamber = function() {
                var ambersands = ["&", "&&", "&&&", "&&", "&",]
                var text = "";
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < ambersands.length; i++) {
                    text += ambersands[i] + "<br>";
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you intend to do here? You're not either writing anything to console nor manipulating an element.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? By the way, for the sake of your own sanity and that of others, please indent your code properly.

Comment: It's ampersand by the way.

Comment: what are the result that was expected?

Comment: "Nothing happens" because... well... nothing happens (that you can see).  Your code is working fine, but it doesn't do anything visible, so you think it's doing nothing.  Try adding `alert(text);` just before the final `};`

Comment: I need to render a pattern of ampersands to the browser like this
&
&&
&&&
&&
&

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to **output the results**.

```js
var testamber = function(){
 var ambersands = ["&", "&&", "&&&", "&&", "&",]
 var text = "";
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < ambersands.length; i++) {
  text += ambersands[i] + "<br>";
 }
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML  = text;
};
```

```html
<button onclick="testamber()">Click here</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: It's ok if you have it in a global (window) scope, but for example using the snippet it wouldn't work, because var x becomes a local variable, and button onclick="x()" only sees the global variables

Comment: also I think in this case just `function testamber(){` would be the easiest

Comment: @Gavriel did you try the snippet?  It works fine, no need for `window.testamber` or even the more conventional `function testamber() {}`

Comment: Thank you Gavriel. The only thing is I need to render to the browser a pattern of ampersands like this

&
&&
&&&
&&
&

Answer (score 0):

> I need to render a pattern of ampersands to the browser like this & && &&& && &

You can *replace* the browser html using `document.write`:

```
<body>
    <button onclick="testamber()">Click here</button>

    <script>
        function testamber() {
            var ampersands = ["&amp;", "&amp;&amp;", "&amp;&amp;&amp;", "&amp;&amp;", "&amp;" ]
            var text = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < ampersands.length; i++) {
                text += ampersands[i] + "<br/>";
            }
            document.write(text);
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

---

or you can provide somewhere for it to go, eg `<div id='output'></div>` and set that, leaving the button, eg `$("#output").text(text);`.  This uses jquery, but you can find equivalent in standard js.